# my script takes 12 seconds to run but later the exact script takes 50 milliseconds to run?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have this piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style>button{disabled:true;}</style>
<script>
var d;
function when_loaded(){
    d=document.getElementById("d");
    //adding nested elements to d using different methods
    //basically just simulating a real situation
    document.title="loading..";
    for(var x=0;x<3500;++x){
        d.appendChild( document.createElement("div"));
        d.appendChild( document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "asd";
        d.appendChild( document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<a href='#'>zxc</a><div>qwe</div>";
        d.appendChild( document.createElement("span")).innerHTML = "asd";
        d.appendChild( document.createElement("div")).appendChild( document.createElement("span")).appendChild( document.createElement("span"));
    }
    document.title="loading done";
    var del=document.getElementById("del");
    var del2=document.getElementById("del2");
    del.style.disabled=del2.style.disabled="false";
}

function del(){
    document.title="deleting";
    var a=new Date().getTime();
    d.innerHTML="";
    var b=new Date().getTime();
    document.title="deleted";
    alert(b-a+" milli seconds taken");
    document.body.innerHTML="you can refresh the page now and try the other button";
}

function del2(){
    document.title="deleting";
    var a=new Date().getTime();
    var c;
    while(c=d.firstChild){
        d.removeChild(c);
    }
    var b=new Date().getTime();
    document.title="deleted";
    alert(b-a+" milli seconds taken");
    document.body.innerHTML="you can refresh the page now and try the other button";
}
</script>
</head><body onload="when_loaded();">
<button id="del" onclick="del();">del</button>
<button id="del2" onclick="del2();">del2</button>
<div id="d"></div>
</body></html>
```

For some reason, when i ran the code the first time (**in Chrome on Windows Vista Home Premium**) and press the second button, it took 12 seconds to run that script.

But after that, I tried to replicate my situation. now it takes only 50 milliseconds.

I closed my browser and reopen it, it is still 50 milliseconds.

I restarted my computer.. it is still 50 milliseconds.

So my question is does anyone know what's causing that abnormality to happen and how do i replicate the abnormality?

Alas, could someone test out the second button and post how long it takes (0.05 seconds or 12 seconds)

Comment: You may be interested in [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com), which allows you to publish performance test and gather statistics from lots of visitors.

Comment: Its hard to tell what could be causing the discrepancy but since all of your runs after the first one are 50 milliseconds, the first one was probably either a fluke or there was another application that was using cpu and causing the script to run slowly.

Comment: I'm seeing times in the 50-60 ms range, with about 10 tabs open in Chrome. Was anything else going on on your machine at the time? For example, if another process was eating up memory or hogging the processor, maybe you were seeing the result of that lag? Since you restarted, maybe you were seeing the result of paging?

Comment: @joekarl could you try it out and tell me ur results ty..

Comment: @ajm you do mean the second button took 50-60 ms to run right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only took 12 seconds once, and never again, then just put it down to some other application hogging the CPU the first time.

Comment: heys post your results too.. how long did it take for you?

Comment: The second button always takes between 47-65ms for me (tried on Windows 7/Chrome 12  and Ubuntu/Chrome 11). However, in Windows the page itself consistently took 10 seconds before it displayed the buttons at all. (Only took 2 seconds in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

You should never append elements to the DOM in a for loop. It keeps having to redraw the page over and over again causing slower performance.

You should create one new element as a wrapper. Append all of the new elements to this element. After the loop is done append it to the page.